# ToolTip on disabled ToolItem - RAP vs RCP

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rap

Is there a way to have a [ToolItem](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FToolItem.html) in a [ToolBar](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FToolBar.html) be disabled and still have it's tooltip?

I know it is not possible by default and workarounds can be used (wrapping within another widget), but because `ToolItem` requires a `ToolBar` parent I couldn't see a solution in this case. Does anyone see how you might "hack" the tooltip workaround in this case?

Don't know if relevant but this is the code:

```
class CustomItem extends org.eclipse.jface.action.ContributionItem {

 @Override
    public void fill(final ToolBar toolBar, final int index) {

      toolItem = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);

      // . . .

    }
}
```

### Update:

The project that this code is needed is a RAP application and  somehow it slipped my mind to think there may be some differences compare with RCP regarding the issue I'm having.

The answer provided by `Subash J` is correct for RCP applications but will not work for RAP.

After talking with a RAP developer he pointed me to this reported bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435750

I updated the title so it's more descriptive of this posts content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can disable a ToolItem in a ToolBar and still show the tooltip. Try the below code.

```
class CustomItem extends org.eclipse.jface.action.ContributionItem {

 @Override
    public void fill(final ToolBar toolBar, final int index) {
      final ToolItem toolItem = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
        toolItem.setText("Sample Tool Item 1");
        toolItem.setEnabled(false);
        toolItem.setToolTipText("Sample Tool Tip 1");

        final ToolItem toolItem2 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
        toolItem2.setText("Sample Tool Item 2");
        toolItem2.setToolTipText("Sample Tool Tip 2");

    }
}
```

Output will be similar like below where `Sample Tool Item 1` is disabled and at the same time tooltip is displayed.

[image: Output]